# Node JS function that return https get request final edited data

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get, request

Hello everybody I have a problem with the Node JS function that I want it to return https get request final edited data, I know there are a lot of solutions for this async problem but I tried them all and still can't figure out what is wrong with my code?
here is my function without any other solutions editing:

```
    function getMovie(apiKey, gen) {
  const baseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=" + apiKey + "&language=en-US&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1&with_genres=" + gen;


  https.get(baseUrl, function (responce) {
    console.log(responce.statusCode);

    var d = "";

    responce.on("data", function (data) {
      d += data;
    });

    responce.on("end", () => {
      const finalData = [];

      const moviesData = JSON.parse(d);
      const result = moviesData.results;
      const maxx = result.length;
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxx);

      const title = result[rand].title;
      const rDate = result[rand].release_date;
      const overview = result[rand].overview;
      const imageRoot = result[rand].poster_path;
      const movieId = result[rand].id;
      const movieRating = result[rand].vote_average;

      // here will push those variables to finalData array
      // then return it

      return finalData;

    });

  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}
```

and want after this finalData returns:

```
const finalResult = getMovie(apiKey, genre);
```

it always returns undefined, How can I fix this? please anyone ca help me with this problem
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using promises using this code:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

function getMovie(url) {
    // returns a promise
    return rp(url).then(body => {
        // make the count be the resolved value of the promise
        let responseJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        return responseJSON.results.count;
    });
}




getMovie(someURL).then(result => {
    // use the result in here
    console.log(`Got result = ${result}`);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('Got error from getMovie ', err);
});
```